# OnClickListener Button inside the Adapter Class Crashing the App in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to store the values from retrofit into a database by pressing a AddtoCartButton but app is getting crashed when I press this button. I am able to retrieve the result from retrofit without any issues but onclicklistener is the issue.

```
Code:
  inner class MoviesAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MovieViewHolder>() {
        private val movies: MutableList<Movie> = mutableListOf()
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MovieViewHolder {
            return MovieViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_movie_layout, parent, false))
        }
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return movies.size
        }
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MovieViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.bindModel(movies[position])
        }
        fun setMovies(data: List<Movie>) {
            movies.addAll(data)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        inner class MovieViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

            val movieGenreTxt : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieGenre)
            val movieYearTxt : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieYear)
            val movieAvatarImage : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieAvatar)
            val movieDescription: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieDescription)

            fun bindModel(movie: Movie) {
            //    movieTitleTxt.text = movie.name
                movieGenreTxt.text = movie.menu
                movieYearTxt.text = movie.price
                Picasso.get().load(movie.picture).into(movieAvatarImage)
                movieDescription.text=movie.description
                var movieName:String= movie.name!!

               var testvar=movie.name.toString()
            }
        }

    }
fun addtocart(view: View)
{
    Toast.makeText(context,"Success on Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
   print testvar 
}
Error:
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Where is `idCart` coming from? It seems like you haven't actually defined that variable.

Comment: It's a button on the activity

Comment: Isn't there a stacktrace when crashing (maybe in logcat)?

Comment: I updated the error message in the below code

Comment: It seems that `idCart` is `null` when calling `idCart.setOnClickListener`.

Comment: That's right.  I am not sure why it's getting null value

Comment: So the relevant code (where `idCart` is/should be set) isn't shown.

Comment: I tried this one too but still same error.                idCart.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Success on Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

Comment: The code of the listener doesn't matter if `idCart` is `null`.

Comment: what might be an issue? All the values coming from Recycler View but Button I created from Activity. Does it causing this issue?

Comment: You need handle click listener on this button inside your Activity, where you found this button.

Comment: @p.alexey Any Idea will be helpful :)

Comment: I am adding that button in this following activity.   return MovieViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_movie_layout, parent, false))

Comment: I suspect the order of invocation might not be what you expect. Without seeing the rest of the code is hard to say, I would recommend making sure `idCart` is not null before setting up your adapter.

Comment: Added  my answer. Thank you all for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Below code solves the purpose.
  Code:
      inner class MoviesAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MovieViewHolder>() {
            private val movies: MutableList<Movie> = mutableListOf()
            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MovieViewHolder {
                return MovieViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_movie_layout, parent, false))
            }
            override fun getItemCount(): Int {
                return movies.size
            }
            override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MovieViewHolder, position: Int) {
                holder.bindModel(movies[position])
            }
            fun setMovies(data: List<Movie>) {
                movies.addAll(data)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            inner class MovieViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

                val movieGenreTxt : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieGenre)
                val movieYearTxt : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieYear)
                val movieAvatarImage : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieAvatar)
                val movieDescription: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieDescription)

                fun bindModel(movie: Movie) {
                //    movieTitleTxt.text = movie.name
                    movieGenreTxt.text = movie.menu
                    movieYearTxt.text = movie.price
                    Picasso.get().load(movie.picture).into(movieAvatarImage)
                    movieDescription.text=movie.description
                    var movieName:String= movie.name!!

                   var testvar=movie.name.toString()
                    val addtocart = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.idCart)
                    addtocart!!.setOnClickListener {
                    print $testvar
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Success on Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        startActivity(intent) }

                }
            }

        }
```